# FabricJS - performance threading

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Sorry if the title was misleading, it's the closest approximation I could come up with, haha.

Okay so I'm using FabricJS for a proof-of-concept for a fabric-printing client, and they require 300PPI images (i.e, freaking huge). Now, if you check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtxdzfks/) I've popped in below you'll see the tiling is done with some while loops which seem to work fine, except for the fact that the whole browser freezes while loading, meaning I can't even stick up a loader icon.

Have I done something horribly wrong, or is that just sorta how it works? The long loading times are fine as long as I can a) put up a loader and b) it doesn't, uh, "He's dead, Jim!" my Chrome. I'm getting the images with base64, if that helps at all.

Cheers everyone!

*EDIT* For context, here's one of the functions that creates a pattern from an uploaded file:

```
function renderMirror(){
showLoader();
var isFullRows = false;
var rowIndex = 0;
var totalHeight = 0;

while(isFullRows == false){
    // let's start with filling up the row's columns. start the width at zero.
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var isFullCols = false;
    var colIndex = 0;

    if(rowIndex % 2){
        var isRowMirrored = false;
    }else{
        var isRowMirrored = true;
    }

    while(isFullCols == false){
        colIndex++

        if(rowIndex == 1){
            console.log('row');
        }

        if(totalWidth >= canvas.width){
            isFullCols = true;
        }

        if(colIndex % 2){
            var isColMirrored = false;
        }else{
            var isColMirrored = true;
        }

        canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            left: totalWidth,
            top: totalHeight,
            fill: pattern,
            flipX: isColMirrored,
            flipY: isRowMirrored,
            height: newImgHeight,
            width: newImgWidth,
            selectable: false
        }));

        totalWidth+= newImgWidth;

        // safeguard
        if(colIndex > 100){
            isFullCols = true;
        }
    }

    // now instantiate the row.
    rowIndex++;
    if(totalHeight >= canvas.height){
        isFullRows = true;
    }

    totalHeight+= newImgHeight;

    // safeguard
    if(rowIndex > 100){
        isFullRows = true;
    }
}
hideLoader();
}
```

The whole thing is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtxdzfks/), if you'd like to have a proper look?

Comment: Have I made a misstep in this post? Not too sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: There is no fiddle in link and please add some code without forcing people to open the fiddle or convert the fiddle to snippet here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've experienced something similar to generate PDF at 300. I tried two different solutions:

1. Using [`webWorkers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which will do the heavy work on the background and is not going to freeze the browser, however this approach was a little bit slower in my use case.
2. The second approach I took was create an endpoint where I get just the base 64 image and then with that data of the image I generate a PDF using `imagemagick` to create the PDF at 300 DPI also I create a virtual canvas with `JS` to generate the real size of the image from a scaled canvas in order to make it a little bit faster as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking a similar thing as your second point, essentially uploading the image at 300DPI, then using a smaller version in the engine.

Haha, no idea why we're both getting downvoted. I'll mark this an answered. Cheers!